# Delete rows containing specific strings in R

Tags: r, string, match, rows

I would like to exclude lines containing a string "REVERSE", but my lines do not match exactly with the word, just contain it.

My input data frame:

```
   Value   Name 
    55     REVERSE223   
    22     GENJJS
    33     REVERSE456
    44     GENJKI
```

My expected output:

```
   Value   Name 
    22     GENJJS
    44     GENJKI
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df[- grep("REVERSE", df$Name),]
```

Or a safer version would be:

```
df[!grepl("REVERSE", df$Name),]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "safer"?

Comment: What if I want to delete the rows containing a "(". The following does not seem to work: df[!grepl("(", df$Name),]

Comment: @nemja The `grepl` function uses regular expressions for the match, which have a syntax where `(` is meaningful. If you set the named parameter `fixed = TRUE` then `grepl` will perform a literal match without using regular expressions, which should work for your use case.

Comment: @JasonMeloHall minus (-) operator does  use negative indexing and negation (!) operator uses logical indexing so negation operator is safer than minus(-)

Comment: How could you modify this to also delete the row above the row that contains the matching string?

Comment: Thanks a lot - googled for about 1h before I found your answer. Works brilliant.

Comment: Hi guys, I tried the code in my contigency table making, although I save my dataframe as a new data, the filtered rows are still kept as a level with "0" entries. how do I ask it to completely delete the rows in the new dataframe?

Answer (score 31):

You could use `dplyr::filter()` and negate a `grepl()` match:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(!grepl('REVERSE', Name))
```

Or with `dplyr::filter()` and negating a `stringr::str_detect()` match:

```
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(Name, 'REVERSE'))
```

Comment: This question asks for many strings. So what happens if you want to remove multiple strings i.e.  `remove.list <- c("REVERSE", "FOO", "BAR, "JJ")`

Comment: Sure, you can do create the list like this:  
`remove.list <- paste(c("REVERSE", "FOO", "BAR", "JJ"), collapse = '|')`
And then filter like this:
`df %>% filter(!grepl(remove.list, Name))`
`df %>% filter(!str_detect(Name, remove.list))`

Comment: How to drop rows based in strings present in two columns, like `filter(!grepl('REVERSE', Name & 'BAR', Name))`, I got the following error trying this way. `! operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types`

Answer (score 21):

Actually I would use:

```
df[ grep("REVERSE", df$Name, invert = TRUE) , ]
```

This will avoid deleting all of the records if the desired search word is not contained in any of the rows.

Answer (score 6):

You can use stri_detect_fixed function from `stringi` package

```
stri_detect_fixed(c("REVERSE223","GENJJS"),"REVERSE")
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function if it's multiple string
`df[!grepl("REVERSE|GENJJS", df$Name),]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use it in the same datafram (df) using the previously provided code

```
df[!grepl("REVERSE", df$Name),]
```

or you might assign a different name to the datafram using this code

```
df1<-df[!grepl("REVERSE", df$Name),]
```

Answer (score 2):

A late answer building on BobD59's and hidden-layer's responses.

This removes multiple specific strings, whilst avoiding deleting all of the records if the desired search word is not contained in any of the rows.

```
df1 <-
   df[!grepl("REVERSE|GENJJS", df$Name), (invert = TRUE), ]
```