# Error: Length of logical index vector must be 1 or 10 (the number of rows), not 47428

Tags: r, vector

Attempting to delete rows containing specific strings in R (as shown in this answer: [Delete rows containing specific strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249702/delete-rows-containing-specific-strings-in-r))

Am consistently getting this error:

> Error: Length of logical index vector must be 1 or 10 (the number of
>   rows), not 47428

Any help would be most appreciated!

```
Reviews<- Reviews[!grep("dog", Reviews$Text)]
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to impossible for anyone to help unless you include the actual code you used in your question, and probably with a reproducible example, so that we can run it ourselves and see exactly what's going on with the data it's being run on.

Comment: It will be much easier for people to try to help you if you post your input (you can post the code you get from using `dput()`, and the code you have tried.

Comment: Thank you. I've added the code. Still figuring out how to add a few rows from the dataframe, which is over 40,000 rows.

Comment: In this case, I think it's easy to spot without the data (but in general, you should aim for including data). You're missing a comma: `Reviews[!grep("dog", Reviews$Text),]` Without the comma you're selecting from just the columns, of which I presume there are only 10.

Comment: You might want to use the `grepl` function instead as that will evaluate to a boolean

Comment: Thank you. The comma and switching to the grepl function helped fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Reviews<- Reviews[!grep("dog", Reviews$Text),]
```

If when you're trying to filter a dataset on a logical expression don't forget to include the comma to identify both the [rows, columns] of the matrix.

Cheers!