# How can I delete a row containing a specific string in R?

Tags: r

I am new to using R. I am using a data set and the missing values have been replaced with "?" before I get the data. I am looking for a way to delete the rows that contain this. It isn't specific to just one row it is in all of them.

I have tried [Delete rows containing specific strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249702/delete-rows-containing-specific-strings-in-r) but it isn't working for me. I have included my code so far below.

```
library(randomForest)
heart <- read.csv(url('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/echocardiogram/echocardiogram.data'))
names <- names(heart)
nrow(heart)
ncol(heart)
names(heart)

colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X11"] <- "survival"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X0"] <- "alive"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X71"] <- "attackAge"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X0.1"] <- "pericardialEffusion"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X0.260"] <- "fractionalShortening"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X9"] <- "epss"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X4.600"] <- "lvdd"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X14"] <- "wallMotionScore"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X1"] <- "wallMotionIndex"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X1.1"] <- "mult"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="name"] <- "patientName"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X1.2"] <- "group"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X0.2"] <- "aliveAfterYear"
names(heart)
```

Comment: `heart[rowSums(heart == "?") == 0, ]`

Comment: have a look at `?grepl`

Comment: Are the values missing at random or is it intentional? Maybe OP should think of whether he or she should keep or omit these strings. na.omit as suggested in an answer below while a good option is not always appropriate for ML.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(randomForest)
heart <- read.csv(url('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/echocardiogram/echocardiogram.data'),na.strings = "?")
names <- names(heart)
nrow(heart)
ncol(heart)
names(heart)

colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X11"] <- "survival"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X0"] <- "alive"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X71"] <- "attackAge"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X0.1"] <- "pericardialEffusion"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X0.260"] <- "fractionalShortening"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X9"] <- "epss"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X4.600"] <- "lvdd"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X14"] <- "wallMotionScore"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X1"] <- "wallMotionIndex"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X1.1"] <- "mult"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="name"] <- "patientName"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X1.2"] <- "group"
colnames(heart)[colnames(heart)=="X0.2"] <- "aliveAfterYear"
names(heart)


heart1 <- na.omit(heart)
```

while importing file you can specify na.string as ? and later using na.omit you can remove all the ? or NA strings

Answer (score 1):

I think this can do what you want.

```
# Do not forget to set stringsAsFactors as false to the read.csv 
# as to make string comparison efficient
heart <- read.csv(url('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/echocardiogram/echocardiogram.data'),stringsAsFactors = F)

# Simpler way to assign column names to the dataframe
colnames(heart) <- c("survival", "alive", "attackAge", "pericardialEffusion", 
                     "fractionalShortening", "epss", "lvdd", "wallMotionScore", 
                     "wallMotionIndex", "mult", "patientName", 
                     "group", "aliveAfterYear")


# You can traverse a dataframe as a matrix using the row and column index 
# as coordinates 

for(r in 1:nrow(heart)){
   for(c in 1:ncol(heart)){
      # For this particular cell you do a comparison 
      # substituting the ? with NA which is the default missing value
      # in R 
      heart[r,c] <- ifelse(heart[r,c]=="?",NA,heart[r,c])
   }
}

# omit the NA rows 
heart <- na.omit(heart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries support reading csv files and specifying strings to be read as missing values. I use the `readr` library most often. Then you can just use `na.omit` and similar functions.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

heart  <- read_csv(
  'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/echocardiogram/echocardiogram.data',
  na=c("", "?")
)


colnames(heart) <- recode(
  colnames(heart),
  "X11" = "survival",
  "X0" = "alive",
  "X71" = "attackAge",
  "X0.1" = "pericardialEffusion",
  "X0.260" = "fractionalShortening",
  "X9" = "epss",
  "X4.600" = "lvdd",
  "X14" = "wallMotionScore",
  "X1" = "wallMotionIndex",
  "X1.1" = "mult",
  "name" = "patientName",
  "X1.2" = "group",
  "X0.2" = "aliveAfterYear"
  )

heart

heart <- na.omit(heart)
```

(Also you can spare some typing with the `recode` function from the `dplyr` package, but your solution for renaming the columns works as good.)