# R subset string values including vertical bar(|)

Tags: r, string, character, subset

I am trying to subset a data based on a column value. I am trying to subset if that specific column has only one level information. Here how my data look like.

```
data <- cbind(v1=c("a", "ab", "a|12|bc", "a|b", "ac","bc|2","b|bc|12"),
            v2=c(1,2,3,5,3,1,2))

> data
     v1        v2 
[1,] "a"       "1"
[2,] "ab"      "2"
[3,] "a|12|bc" "3"
[4,] "a|b"     "5"
[5,] "ac"      "3"
[6,] "bc|2"    "1"
[7,] "b|bc|12" "2"
```

I want to subset only with the character values that were not including "|", like below:

```
> data
     v1        v2 
[1,] "a"       "1"
[2,] "ab"      "2"
[3,] "ac"      "3"
```

basically, I am trying to get rid of two-level (x|y) or three level values (x|y|z). Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

Comment: A `stringr` possibility: `data[sapply(data,function(x) !str_detect(x,"\\|"))]`

Comment: Several related examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22249702/5325862

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `grep` to find the row that have `|`, use the `invert` option to get the row index of elements that have no `|`, use that to subset the rows of the `matrix`

```
data[grep("|", data[,1], invert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE), ]
#   v1   v2 
#[1,] "a"  "1"
#[2,] "ab" "2"
#[3,] "ac" "3"
```

NOTE: The `fixed = TRUE` is used or else it will check with the regex mode on and `|` is a metacharacter for `OR` condition.  Other option are to escape (`\\|`) or place it inside square brackets (`[|]`) to capture the literal character (when `fixed = FALSE`)

Comment: Thanks! Does this method work when I am using data frames instead of matrices?

Comment: @amisos55  Yes, it would work except if is a tibble.  Then you may need `data[[1]]` instead of `data[,1]`

Answer (score 3):

Using logical `grepl` this can be done as follows. I will leave it in two code lines for clarity but it's straightforward to make of it a one-liner.

```
i <- !grepl("\\|", data[, 1])
data[i, ]
#     v1   v2 
#[1,] "a"  "1"
#[2,] "ab" "2"
#[3,] "ac" "3"
```