# R: Delete ID if any of the rows within ID contain specific strings (or multiple partial strings) in longitudinal format?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, delete-row, longitudinal

I would like to delete ID in any row that contains certain strings (A or D) within ID.
Here is my data frame:

```
id   time   dx
1     1     C
1     2     B
2     1     A
2     2     C
2     3     B
3     1     D
```

I would like the following:

```
id    time  dx
 1     1     C
 1     2     B
```

Based on the earlier post regarding this ([Delete rows containing specific strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249702/delete-rows-containing-specific-strings-in-r)), I tried d %>% filter(!grepl('A|D', dx)). However, it only deletes the rows that contain A or D, not the whole IDs. I'd appreciate any help!

##Update: All the below answers worked well for the above post. Thank you all! Note that for this post, I simplified my data frame, and later on, I realized that I actually needed R codes to delete the IDs with certain partial strings (e.g., A or B0) from the following data frame. I was able to achieve this by modifying the first r2evans' answer: d %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(!any(str_detect(dx, "A|B0"))) %>% ungroup(). I have included the note here in case someone needs it. I would appreciate any additional suggestions.

Data frame:

```
id time dx
1   1   C01
1   2   B1
2   1   A34
2   2   C01
2   3   B1
3   1   B01X
```

The results I wanted:

```
id time dx
1   1   C01
1   2   B1
```

Answer (score 3):

`grep` is the wrong tool for this based on your question and sample data, I think `%in%` is the better way to go. Combine that with natural `dplyr:group_by` and an `any(.)` conditional, and we get our results

### dplyr

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!any(dx %in% c("A", "D"))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#      id  time dx   
#   <int> <int> <chr>
# 1     1     1 C    
# 2     1     2 B
```

### base R

```r
dat[ave(dat$dx, dat$id, FUN = function(z) !any(z %in% c("A", "D"))) == "TRUE",]
#   id time dx
# 1  1    1  C
# 2  1    2  B
```

(`ave` requires that its output be the same class as its input which, in this case, is `character`. That's why I'm comparing against the *string* `"TRUE"` instead of using it as a literal `TRUE`.)

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), time = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), dx = c("C", "B", "A", "C", "B", "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you, r2evans! Both worked. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `subset` in `base R`

```
subset(df1, !id %in% id[dx %in% c("A", "D")])
  id time dx
1  1    1  C
2  1    2  B
```

---

Or a similar option with `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df1, !id %in% id[dx %in% c("A", "D")])
  id time dx
1  1    1  C
2  1    2  B
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), time = c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), dx = c("C", "B", "A", "C", "B", "D")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thank you, akrun! Both worked. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  df,
  !ave(dx %in% c("A", "D"), id, FUN = any)
)
```

gives

```
  id time dx
1  1    1  C
2  1    2  B
```

Comment: Thank you, ThomasisCoding! It worked. I upvoted your answer.