# Remove rows containing specific strings

Tags: r, grepl

I want to remove rows containing specific strings which I stored in a separate vector.

I tried everything from
[Delete rows containing specific strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249702/delete-rows-containing-specific-strings-in-r) and [Remove Rows From Data Frame where a Row matches a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650510/remove-rows-from-data-frame-where-a-row-matches-a-string)
but it always removes every row and my output is empty
I tried it with an example and it works fine, but not for my input and my remove_list

My input is:

```
   ID Aufzeichnungen                                                                 
   <dbl> <chr>                                                                          
 1     1 "Aufzeichnungen"                                                               
 2     1 "07.03.22   A: stechender Schmerz"                                             
 3     1 "    scharfkantig"                                                             
 4     1 "D/B:"                                                                         
 5     1 "T:"                                                                           
 6     1 "pat aht an 36 üz distal"                                                      
 7     1 " seit paartagen"                                                              
 8     1 "36 vipr++"                                                                    
 9     1 " perk-"                                                                       
10     1 " keine c zu entdekcne"                                                        
11     1 "üz bilfuird"                                                                  
12     1 "pat aufgekläörtggf  RÖ um c auszuschileßen"                                   
13     1 " pat verweigert RÖ aus Angst vor Strahlung"                                   
14     1 " pat"                                                                         
15     1 "aufgeklärt angst nicht nötig und c unter fllg oder apprx nicht auszuschließen"
16     1 ""                                                                             
17     1 "pat knirscht"                                                                 
18     1 " schiene empohlen"                                                            
19     1 " pat meldet sich.."
```

and I want to remove every row containing strings from this list:

```
remove_list <- paste(c("einverst", "empf", "raten", "aufgeklä", "nicht", "weiß nicht", "bespr", "soll",
                       "kein", "?", "raten", "klären", "überprüf", "erst, wenn", "verweiger", 
                       "notwendig"), collapse = '|')
```

Logically it should remove rows 10, 12, 13, 15

My codes are:

```
removed <-  PKV[grep(remove_list, PKV$Aufzeichnungen, invert = TRUE), ]
removed <- PKV %>% filter(!grepl(remove.list, PKV$Aufzeichnungen ))
```

and also every variant with str_detect

But the output looks always like this:

```
# A tibble: 0 × 2
# Groups:   ID [0]
# … with 2 variables: ID <dbl>, Aufzeichnungen <chr>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you also provide your data frame using `dput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- We can first `grep` the indices of the rows contains one of `remove_list` words , then exclude them from your data.frame

```
remove_ind <- lapply(strsplit(remove_list , "\\|")[[1]] ,
              \(x) grep(x , PKV$Aufzeichnungen , fixed = T)) |>
              unlist() |> unique()

#> [1] 12 15 10 13

PKV[-remove_ind,]
```

- output

```
   ID                   Aufzeichnungen
1   1                   Aufzeichnungen
2   1 07.03.22   A: stechender Schmerz
3   1                     scharfkantig
4   1                             D/B:
5   1                               T:
6   1          pat aht an 36 üz distal
7   1                   seit paartagen
8   1                        36 vipr++
9   1                            perk-
11  1                      üz bilfuird
14  1                              pat
16  1                                 
17  1                     pat knirscht
18  1                 schiene empohlen
19  1                pat meldet sich..
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
remove_list <- c("einverst", "empf", "raten", "aufgeklä", "nicht", "weiß nicht", "bespr", "soll",
                       "kein", "?", "raten", "klären", "überprüf", "erst, wenn", "verweiger", 
                       "notwendig")

mylist <- c("notwendig","einverst","1","2" )

mylist[!mylist %in% remove_list]
#> [1] "1" "2"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have a question mark in `remove_list` but `?` has a meaning in regex. So I suggest you escape it, i.e.

```
remove_list <- paste(c("einverst", "empf", "raten", "aufgeklä", "nicht", "weiß nicht", "bespr", "soll",
                       "kein", "\\?", "raten", "klären", "überprüf", "erst, wenn", "verweiger", 
                       "notwendig"), collapse = '|')
```

Then select the right rows, using the inverse of the grepl using `!`

```
PKV[!grepl(remove_list, PKV$AUFZEICHNUNGEN),]
```

Example of escaping `?`:

```
#first rows of your data
dt <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AUFZEICHNUNGEN = c("Aufzeichnungen", 
"07.03.22   A: stechender Schmerz", "    scharfkantig", "D/B:", 
" keine c zu entdekcne", "pat aufgekläörtggf  RÖ um c auszuschileßen", 
" seit paartagen", "36 vipr++")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

#grepl without escaping ?
grepl("?", PKV$AUFZEICHNUNGEN)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

#grepl with escaping ?
grepl("\\?", PKV$AUFZEICHNUNGEN)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```