# Deleting rows with certain strings

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to delete entire rows that contain certain infromation for example:

I would like to get rid of every row that contians the string **red**.

| color | num | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | 10 | Mon |
| blue | 6 | Tus |
| green | 2 | Thur |
| red | 1 | Wed |
| orange | 7 | Sun |
| pink | 12 | Fri |
| yellow | 25 | Sat |
| red | 35 | Fri |

Comment: Hello Cole! as you might have seen in the tour or at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in the help centre. Researching if there are similar questions is also a practice at stackoverflow. Try searching for "condition drop rows".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete rows containing specific strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249702/delete-rows-containing-specific-strings-in-r)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter rows which contain a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filter-rows-which-contain-a-certain-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter option to get rid of the rows where column has certain values.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(color = c("red", "blue", "green", "red", "orange","pink","yellow","red"), 
                 num = c(10, 6, 2, 1, 7,12,25,35),
                 day=c("Mon","Tus","Thur","Wed","Sun","Fri","Sat","Fri"))
df %>%
  filter(color!='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```r
cleaned_df <- orig_df[orig_df$color != "red",]

# Or more safely
cleaned_df <- orig_df[! orig_df$color %in% "red",]
```

I say *more safely* because the first will give you trouble if the `color` column contains missing values.

Answer (score 0):

- We can use

```
library(dplyr)

df |> filter(!grepl("red" , color))
```

- Output

```
   color num  day
1   blue   6  Tus
2  green   2 Thur
3 orange   7  Sun
4   pink  12  Fri
5 yellow  25  Sat
```